# Should I use an interface for Type Codes?

Tags: vb.net, interface, types

I am working on a project that has several different codes.  These codes all basically are used this way:

```
CodeKey
Description

GetList
GetSpecific
SetProperties
```

All of my classes implement this.  I am hesitent, however, to use an interface because of one problem--the type Codes vary by type.  Some are strings, some are integers, some are bytes.  The only way I could see using an interface would be to make the typeCode an object in the interface and then cast whenever I needed to use it, but that seems a bit silly.  Any ideas?  This is in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generic interface for it as I read it.

```
Interface IYourType(Of T)
  Property CodeKey As T
  Property Description As String
  Sub GetList...
  Sub GetSpecific...
  Sub SetProperties...
End Interface
```

I am not sure I understand your question completely, but your type issue is an obvious use of generics.

Good luck,
- Dan

Comment: Dan,

Thanks so much.  This was exactly the same conclusion I came to searching around Google.  It looks like it is going to work perfectly and prevent much casting :)  Thanks a bunch!

In Christ,


Austin